# Module Import Error for Pypi module

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to import a pypi module (thinkx 1.1.2) into spyder.   It is installed on anaconda and showing up on conda list.  I my python path folders is my anaconda folder.  When I attempt to import thinkx into spyder I get : 
    import thinkx
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    import thinkx

ImportError: No module named 'thinkx'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [module README](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkX), `thinkx` does not expose package named `thinkx`.

> It provides the following modules:
>
> - `thinkbayes`: Code for Think Bayes.
> - `thinkstats2`: Code for Think Stats, 2nd edition
> - `thinkbayes2`: Code for Think Bayes, 2nd edition, not yet published.
> - `thinkdsp`: Code for Think DSP
> - `thinkplot`: Plotting code used in all of the books, mostly wrapper functions for matplotlib.pyplot

Try:

```
import thinkbayes
```